# Getting coordinates from google maps place autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, ionic2

I would like to use the google place autocomplete in an ionic2 project. I have found this npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-google-places-autocomplete

which works as it describes. However in the callback=detail($event[0]) I don't get the coordinates of the selected address. What I get is a javascript object that has information about the address I have typed in.

Is there any way to have a google place autocomplete in an ionic2 project that gives me the coordinates of the selected address.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) shows javascript code which does exactly what you want.  Are you using a particular library where you cannot access the native api?

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-google-places-autocomplete which doesn't give the coordinates. However the autocomplete works as expected. Furthermore, I'm using google place autocomplete without google maps. Instead I'm using leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

The callback that the npm package has is the same described in https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete. This doesn't return the location but it returns the place_id.

​With the place_id you can call the place details (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) to obtain the lat and lon.